# Is it possible to disable windows network bridge remotely?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a virtual server with Windows Server 2012 system and a Debian Linux in VirtualBox within it.

I accidentally set a network bridge between the internet connection and the VirtualBox host-only network on the Windows host, and now I have no means of access to the Windows system.

Is there any way I could access the Windows system and disable the network bridge?

Update:

I'm not able to connect to the hosted Debian system (to whose network I've bridget the internet access).

Comment: You mean a VPS ? If so, your hosting provider may offer console access solutions. Where is your Windows Server 2012 hosted ?

Comment: @Ob1lan: Yes, VPS. It's hosted at strato.de. They offer KVM, which is my last resort. But the question is meant more generally, i.e. ehether there evere may be the possibility to work around this kind of misconfiguration.

Comment: If the server is not accessible via the network nor via a console, obviously you can't edit its settings/configuration... Exept if you configured Scheduled tasks or scripts to perform operations on a schedule or on particular events...